# Do B1/B2 visa-holders need to fill any additional forms in their future travels to the States

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, turkish-citizens

I am a Turkish citizen living in Spain. I have a 10 year B1/B2 visa that I obtained two years ago for attending a conference in the USA. Soon, I will travel back to the States (again from Spain) for another conference.

I wonder if I need to fill some forms. I hope that I am good with my current visa. My passport will expire in two years.

Comment: I want to add that, though not relevant for the OP's case, there is one case where people with B1/B2 visas might need to do something additional before traveling to the US -- people traveling on Chinese (PRC) passports with 10-year B1/B2 visas need to enroll in EVUS before traveling to the US; the EVUS will be valid for 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only form you need to fill out is the landing card (and you can skip that if you use the APC kiosk).

As always, you might be asked questions about your visit, so you should carry relevant documents to demonstrate the purpose of your visit, your ability to support yourself financially, and your intention to leave the US.